# Reading the pdf file from Assests folder

Tags: android, pdf

I have code for getting the file from sdcard and display the pdf file using the jar called PDFViewer.jar and works like a charm , now i have my pdf file in assests folder how to get the file and display ?

this is my code for reading the pdf from sdcard:

```
public class First extends ListActivity {

    String[] pdflist;
    File[] imagelist;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        File images = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return ((name.endsWith(".pdf")));
            }
        });
        pdflist = new String[imagelist.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < imagelist.length; i++) {
            pdflist[i] = imagelist[i].getName();
        }
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String path = imagelist[(int) id].getAbsolutePath();
        openPdfIntent(path);
    }

    private void openPdfIntent(String path) {
        try {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
            intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

package android.pdf.reader;

import net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Second extends PdfViewerActivity 
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public int getPreviousPageImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.left_arrow;
}

public int getNextPageImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.right_arrow;
}

public int getZoomInImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.zoom_in;
}

public int getZoomOutImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.zoom_out;
}

public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() {
    return R.layout.pdf_file_password;
}

public int getPdfPageNumberResource() {
    return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber;
}

public int getPdfPasswordEditField() {
    return R.id.etPassword;
}

public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() {
    return R.id.btOK;
}

public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() {
    return R.id.btExit;
}

public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() {
    return R.id.pagenum_edit;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream ims assetManager.open("pdf_name.pdf");
```

Comment: can you please elaborate? as i am passing pdflist to adapter

Comment: So you asked how to read a pdf file - correct? In your assets folder,if you have a pdf file called pdf_name.pdf, then you can read it by calling the Android's AssetManager's open method.